# Google Analytic with grub gives me 404 error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, google-analytics, garb-gem

I am beginner to ror development.I am developing small RoR application in which i want to integrate Google analytic. I am using  [Garb gem for thid](https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb) 
According to gem I used

```
Garb::Session.login(username, password)// for initial session setup
```

after that select proper profile

```
profile = Garb::Management::Profile.all.detect {|p| p.web_property_id == 'UA-XXXXXXX-X'}
```

but when I tried to get the data it gives me error

```
Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.eql => '/'})

// error
Error 404 (Not Found)!!1
The requested URL /analytics/feeds/accounts/default was not found on this server.
```

How to solve this problem is there any way to handle this situation. Or whether I am doind something wrong?

Need Help.... Thank you.....